# Pass JSON to Postgres procedure from Node.JS

Tags: node.js, json, postgresql

I'm new to node postgres, I have a stored procedure that takes a json object. I don't know what's wrong here. I use pg-promise and by the docs I used client.func() to pass params to the stored procedure. The procedure works when I sent json in DBeaver.

```
    const json = { requesttype: "checkemailaddress_availability", 
                   emailaddress: "abc@xyz.com" 
                 };

    client.func('r1.process_request', json).then(data => {
    console.log('DATA', data);
    }).catch(err => {
        console.log('ERR', err);
    }
    );
```

Log:

```
     name: 'error',
     length: 220,
     severity: 'ERROR',
     code: '42883',
     detail: undefined,
     hint: 'No function matches the given name and argument types. You might 
     need to add explicit type casts.',
     position: '15',
     internalPosition: undefined,
     internalQuery: undefined,
     where: undefined,
     schema: undefined,
     table: undefined,
     column: undefined,
     dataType: undefined,
     constraint: undefined,
     file: 'parse_func.c',
     line: '528',
     routine: 'ParseFuncOrColumn' }
```

Comment: Looks like an invalid use of formatting parameters. Try `client.func('r1.process_request', [json])` instead.

Comment: Tried what you said, still doesn't work.

Comment: Start using [pg-monitor](https://github.com/vitaly-t/pg-monitor), see exactly what query is being executed, then it is much easier to find and fix any query-related issue.